# How to cancel repeated work scheduled with RACScheduler?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I've scheduled a work with `- (RACDisposable *)after:(NSDate *)date repeatingEvery:(NSTimeInterval)interval withLeeway:(NSTimeInterval)leeway schedule:(void (^)(void))block;`. How to cancel it?

As far as I understood from description I should use `RACDisposable*` returned from this method.
Should I just call `- dispose` on this object?
Should It be configured somehow for cancelation?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's nothing else you need to do.

`RACDisposable` just represents a cancelable action, or resources to clean up. In the same way that you invoke `-dispose` to cancel a subscription, you can use it to cancel a recurring scheduled block.

As an aside, the `RACScheduler` methods are fairly low-level, and having to invoke them directly is *usually* an indicator of overly imperative code. If you can, try to use existing `RACSignal` operators to accomplish what you want in a more functional way.

Comment: I've just tried to schedule server synchronisation. It appeared that I have to stop this sync at some point.
And also I need to cancel request operation on ```-dispose```.
Should I wrap a request into ```RACCommand```? What is the best way to perform this work in functional reactive world?
Thanks

Comment: You can use `+[RACSignal interval:]` to create a signal that fires at a certain rate, and then use `-flattenMap:` to incorporate signals of "work" that should occur whenever it does fire. Unfortunately, it's kinda hard to give bite-sized explanations about RAC patterns, so you may want to check out some of the resources in this list: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#new-to-reactivecocoa